# Subscribing to Redis expire events in c# driver?

Tags: c#, redis

If you add expiration's to entities you are adding into Redis e.g. in ServiceStack.Redis:

```
redisClient.Set(elementKey, "some cached value", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2));
```

how can you then subscribe to the element's expiration. The desired outcome would be something ala:

```
redisClient.Subscribe(elementKey, "expire", DoSomethingBasedOnKey)
```

Comment: Maybe you don't know that expire message won't be published when the key gets expired :D

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there ways to monitor or catch when keys do expire, or is that concept not possible in Redis?

Comment: You need to combine some time of scheduler to run a task when the Redis key expires. You can schedule the task at the same time that Redis key expires

Comment: Sorry, I've not used Redis much so aren't aware of the options or best approach. Is the scheduler, and task concept something built into Redis or would that be an external system that's polling the system periodically?

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can subscribe to expired keys events, but like Matias said it may take some time until Redis will publish the event.

Redis has Keyspace notifications, you can read about it [here](https://redis.io/topics/notifications),

> Keyspace notifications allows clients to subscribe to Pub/Sub channels in order to receive events affecting the Redis data set in some way.
>
> **Type of events**
>
> Keyspace notifications are implemented sending two distinct type of events for every operation affecting the Redis data space. For instance a DEL operation targeting the key named mykey in database 0 will trigger the delivering of two messages, exactly equivalent to the following two PUBLISH commands:
>
> PUBLISH **keyspace@0**:mykey del
>   PUBLISH **keyevent@0**:del mykey

So what you need is to subscribe to the channel that will publish a message on expired command of keyevent(work also when ttl is reached), it prefix will be like so:
"**keyevent@0**:expired"

Timing accuracy wasn't matter at my case so I've implemented it like so using the ServiceStack C# Redis client:

```
string EXPIRED_KEYS_CHANNEL = "__keyevent@0__:expired";    
using (IRedisClient client = redisClient.GetClient())
{
    using (var cacheSubscription = client.CreateSubscription())
    {
        cacheSubscription.OnMessage += (ch, expiredKey) =>
        {                            
            FireOnKeyExpired(expiredKey);
        };
        cacheSubscription.SubscribeToChannels(EXPIRED_KEYS_CHANNEL);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Make sure to configure redis.conf to allow key events on expired keys:

notify-keyspace-events Ex

Or on the fly like so(configuration may be lost when instance is restarted)

config set notify-keyspace-events Ex

Comment: Is there a way to receive only expired events for a specific key?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't know that expire messages won't get exactly published [when keys get expired:](http://redis.io/topics/notifications)

> ### Timing of expired events
>
> Keys with a time to live associated are
>   expired by Redis in two ways:
>
> - When the key is accessed by a command and is found to be expired.
> - Via a background system that looks for expired keys in background, incrementally, in order to be able to also
>     collect keys that are never accessed.

I would suggest you that your best bet is using some task scheduler like the built-in Windows Task Scheduler or Quartz.NET to schedule a task to publish a message to some custom Redis PubSub channel exactly when the key must get expired.